# Ionic build failed for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to make a build for iOS of ionic app but when I add platform it give me following error :

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
> cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: io.enigmatex.lapulga
    Name: Lapulga
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.5
Installing "cordova-plugin-actionsheet" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-facebook4" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.7.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" already installed on ios.
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Installing "cordova-sms-plugin" for ios
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios
Installing "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" for ios
Installing "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-actionsheet@2.3.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-actionsheet" already installed on ios.
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-dialogs@2.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs" already installed on ios.
Discovered plugin "call-number" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" already installed on android.
Plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" already installed on ios.
Adding mx.ferreyra.callnumber to package.json
Saved plugin info for "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.5.5 into config.xml file ...
Error: Command failed: /Data/Other Projects/Updated Project/lapulga/platforms/android/cordova/version
/bin/sh: /Data/Other: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:288:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:599:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add ios --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
        information.
```

---

System Info :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 13 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.8.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.5.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

In the beginning it gives me an error of google maps and one signal then I remove them and after that it gives me this error

I just want to have iOS build that I'll upload to the Apple app store. I'm stuck on this for past 4 days and didn't find any workable solution.

P.S : I'm not a ionic developer I just need to upload this and app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is having problems with spaces in the path.  I would move the project to a directory with no spaces in the path and try again.

Comment: Thanks, That works!!
Now please tell me how add again google maps and onesignal, I tried following but it give me error:

cordova plugin add googlemaps
Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "googlemaps". Please try adding it again.

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer to help others, and you aren't supposed to ask questions in comments, however, you are probably missing the API Key and Secret for Google Maps Plugin.  See the github page for details: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps